# How can i reach getResources() and Context except Activity class?

Tags: android, resources, android-context

I know this question is general but I am always face to face this problem.
My question is I can    reach `getResource()` or `getContext()` in `Activity` but when I want to use a class without activity
example:
`public class MapOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay`

I can not reach `getResources()` or `Context`.

How can I do that anybody know any trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemizedOverlay in not extending `android.content.Context`.

You can create the construcor like

```
private Context mContext;    
public MapOverlay(Context context){
this.mContext=context;
}
```

and then use the `mContext` field to call `getResource()` or `getContext()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it the following way:

- Create a class that extends `Application`, say `MyApp`.
- Declare a `private static Context context` field
- Declare a (static) getter for the `context` field
- Initialize the field in `onCreate(): context = this`

Now context is available across all application via `MyApp.context()`

Comment: Hi Ash thx for clear answer.I want to ask i dont use activity what is for onCreate?

Comment: `Application` class has `onCreate()` method that is executed when application starts. Don't forget to declare it in the manifest: `<application android:name=".MyApp" ...`

Comment: you missunderstand me if you add oncreate it is not different from acvitiy it is same?

Comment: Look, `Application` is not an `Activity`, it is a place for maintaining global application state: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html You can create a static field, initialize it in `onCreate()` and access it from _any_ other class in your application. No need to pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just expose a public method inside your MapOverlay that takes a Context.

```
  public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
}
```